# SQL create a temp table or update table field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have created a new table from various joined tables with some logic inside of it to determine certain process time based on two time stamps like the following.

```
select  t1.date_created,
        t1.date_due,
        (t1.date_closed - t1.date_created)*86400 as due_time
        t2.date_created.
        t2.date_closed,
        (t2.date_closed - t2.date_created)*86400 as process_time
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 on t1.ID = T2.table1ID
```

Bear in mind I have made several more joins (just an example).
Now I wish to determine if the t2 process time is bigger than t1 time like the following.

```
case   
  when t1.due_time > t2.process_time
  then 1
  else 0
end as ind_within_due_time
```

Now my question is what the best practice would be.

A. To create a temp table with the entire join logic. then create a new table to determine to ind_within_due_time and drop the old table.

or B. create a table with the join logic and create a empty column in the table to then write an update script to allocate the value afterwards?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using MySQL or SQL Server.  Tagging both is confusing.

Comment: sql server, appologies.

Comment: You could create a VIEW.  If you are not familiar with these, they are a way to create a virtual table, based on a query.  For more see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cant you just do this

```
SELECT date_created, 
       date_due, 
       due_time date_created. date_closed, 
       process_time, 
       CASE 
              WHEN t1.due_time > t2.process_time THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
       END AS ind_within_due_time 
FROM   (SELECT     t1.date_created, 
                   t1.date_due, 
                   (t1.date_closed - t1.date_created)*86400 AS due_time t2.date_created. t2.date_closed,
                   (t2.date_closed - t2.date_created)*86400 AS process_time
        FROM       table1                                   AS t1 
                  INNER JOIN table2 
                  ON t1.id = t2.table1id) a
```

or in same select you can do this

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
       WHEN (t1.date_closed - t1.date_created)*86400 > (t2.date_closed - t2.date_created)*86400 THEN 1
       ELSE 0 
   END AS ind_within_due_time, 
   t1.date_created, 
   t1.date_due, 
   (t1.date_closed - t1.date_created)*86400 AS due_time t2.date_created. t2.date_closed, 
   (t2.date_closed - t2.date_created)*86400 AS process_time
...
```